# Clearing bad input

Tags: c

```
do {
     printf("Enter endpoints of interval to be integrated (low hi): ");
     test = scanf("%lf %lf", &low, &hi);

     if (test != 2) {
        badInput(low);
        badInput(hi);
        printf("Error: Improperly formatted input");
     }

     else if(low > hi)
        printf("Error: low must be < hi\n");

} while ((test != 2 || low > hi));
```

In this code I'm trying to eliminate user input error. Currently, my issue is if the user enters letters instead of numbers the prompt just repeat without letting new user input.

What would I need to put in the function `badInput` in order to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

> > Currently, my issue is if the user enters letters instead of numbers the prompt just repeat without letting new user input.

The `scanf()` expects two double input from user:

```
test = scanf("%lf %lf", &low, &hi);
```

When you give letters instead of number as input to `scanf()`, it does not consume them because they do not match with the given format string and leaves them in the input buffer. You must have note that when you are giving letters instead of numbers, the `scanf()` must be returning `0` because it does not consume them. Since, `scanf()` does not consume the invalid input, in next iteration of loop `scanf()` find the unconsumed invalid input in the buffer and again skip them. Thats why your program does not stop for input when giving letters as input. To solve this problem, you have to flush the invalid input out of the buffer. You can do:

```
do {
    printf("Enter endpoints of interval to be integrated (low hi): ");
    test = scanf("%lf %lf", &low, &hi);

    if (test != 2) {
        badInput(low);
        badInput(hi);
        printf("Error: Improperly formatted input");
        int c;
        while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)  // <=== This loop read the extra input characters and discard them
            /* discard the character */;
    }
    ......
    ......
```